# VB Scripting for counting the client connection

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, vbscript, share

I want to Count the number of client connection connected to a shared folder using vbscript.  I can use any service but not WMIservice.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use WMI?

```
sComputer = "."
sShare = "C$"

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colConnections = oWMI.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Share.Name=""" & 
sShare & """} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_ConnectionShare")

WScript.Echo colConnections.Count & " open connections on \\" & sComputer & 
"\" & sShar
```

(Source: http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vbscript/12834/VBScript-and-Shares )